# Specify java/system properties in external file via Bash

Tags: bash, solr, systemctl

I wanted to know if it is possible to put the system/java properties into a text file and some how to have them read and passed to the start command below. It could be any startup script really. This is just an example.

```
$SOLR_HOME/bin/solr start -Dsolr.default.confdir=$HOME/my-conf-dir -Dsolr.data.home=$HOME/my-data-dir
```

This start script will be called from system ctl and I don't want to put the -D options hard coded. I would like that they are in a file that I can control.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That would need to be application specific depending on your system and application, since you don't want properties from one application to leak into other applications.

For Solr [this is stored in `/etc/default/solr.in.sh`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/taking-solr-to-production.html#TakingSolrtoProduction-Environmentoverridesincludefile) if you've used the default `install_solr_service.sh` script.

As far as I know there is no general support for using property files with the JVM directly, and it's up to the applications to support it as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a properties file `solr.properties`:

```
# this is a comment
solr.default.confdir=$HOME/my-conf-dir

# this is another comment
solr.data.home=$HOME/my-data-dir

solr.foo=$FOO
```

Then the following commands

```
export FOO=bar
grep '^[^#][^=]*=' <(envsubst '$HOME $FOO' < solr.properties)
```

would substitute the `$HOME` variable with the home directory and `$FOO` with `bar` in `solr.properties`
and `grep` for all lines not starting with a comment `#` and containing a `=` character.

The second command extended to

```
arr=( $(printf -- '-D%s\n' $(grep '^[^#][^=]*=' <(envsubst '$HOME $FOO' < solr.properties))) )
```

would save the properties with `-D` appended in array `arr`.

The complete start script would be

```
#!/bin/bash

export FOO=bar
arr=( $(printf -- '-D%s\n' $(grep '^[^#][^=]*=' <(envsubst '$HOME $FOO' < solr.properties))) )
$SOLR_HOME/bin/solr start "${arr[@]}"
```